# No query results for model

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/books/{book}/chapter/{chapter}', [
            'uses' =>'PostController@index'])->where(['book'=>'[-a-z0-9]+','chapter'=>'[0-9]+']);
```

(Model)
**Chapter.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Chapter extends Model
{

}
```

I am getting error like below

[image]

Chapter Model is like below.

**Chapter.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Chapter extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'id','book_id','title','preface','number','createdAt','updatedAt','createdBy','updatedBy','deletedBy';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need insert **your fields** inside your model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Chapter extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'chapter';
    protected $fillable = ['id','book_id','title','preface','number','createdAt','updatedAt','createdBy','updatedBy','deletedBy']; 
}
```

Insert all fields of chapter model inside your model. And try again

Comment: Thanks @Diego Cespedes for your reply. I added **Chapter** model. But it is still not working. Thanks

Comment: This code is wrong. Do you mean the `$fillable` array?

Answer (score 0):

You define your fields in the `$table` property with a *wrong syntax*. `$table` should have the name of your database table!
Additionally, you can set your mass assignment fillable fields.

```
class Chapter extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'chapter'; // database table name
    protected $fillable = ['id','book_id','title','preface','number','createdAt','updatedAt','createdBy','updatedBy','deletedBy']; // 
}
```

If you want to define your fields in your model, you can use the `$fields` (example from https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/model-definition):

```
$fields = [
    'firstName' => [
        'cast' => 'string',  // default, can be omitted
        'maxlength' => 100, 
        'column' => 'first_name', 
    ],
    'lastName' => [
        'cast' => 'string',  // default, can be omitted
        'maxlength' => 100, 
        'column' => 'last_name', 
    ],
    'isAdmin' => [
        'cast' => 'boolean',
        'column' => 'is_admin', 
    ],
]
```